# Ubuntu opens to tty, apt-get is not working

Tags: gnome, tty

So I was trying to install some packages, but they were sort of broken so an answer recommended that I use "apt-get remove" to remove the corrupted versions and re-install them. While doing that I got a warning that said "this could be harmful" then I thought meh and wrote "Yes, do as I say!".

Next thing I know, most of my windows were closing and icons disappearing so I had to forcefully close the terminal. I tried opening a new one to re-install everything but it wouldn't open, so I restarted my laptop.

When Ubuntu opened again, it showed me the black and white terminal (I believe it is called tty) and when I tried to use apt-get to maybe fix things and install everything I removed (and perhaps a desktop), it said the "apt-get" package was not found.

So yeah, I kind of messed up my OS but I want to know if there's a way to fix this without reinstalling Ubuntu because there's a lot of software that I would rather not go through installing them again..

Comment: See your bash history to find out what commands did you run, then install the missing packages that was removed.You might need to install ```ubuntu-desktop``` package too.

Comment: Is there a way I can do that without apt-get command? Because this package was uninstalled too..

Comment: Which ubuntu version do you use?

Comment: @ParsaMousavi 18.04

Comment: So run ```wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apt/apt_1.6.1_amd64.deb ; sudo dpkg -i apt_1.6.1_amd64.deb```

Comment: @ParsaMousavi Ok thank you I will try this. Also, I'm using dual boot. Is using Windows to manually download packages and place them into Ubuntu directories a smart option?

Comment: It would probably help if we knew more of what you deleted (I can't imagine what you removed that would cause https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/apt to be removed..), but `wget` to grab & then `dpkg` to install is where I'd go until you can use higher level tools..

Comment: @DiaaEldinMalek If you have access to the ubuntu partition in your windows , then yes.

Comment: @ParsaMousavi The commands worked, I did apt-get upgrade & check because they seemed suitable for my situation. How do I know which other vital packages are missing (other than waiting for errors to pop up)?

Comment: @guiverc The package I was removing earlier was libstdc++ (apt-get purge). I knew it was a necessary package but I didn't realize it would wreck the OS like that. I guess it's because I used purge instead of simply remove? Not sure

Comment: For informational/learning purposes, look at my prior provided link on the `apt` package; it lists the *depends* packages `apt` requires.. ie. when you removed the *gnu C++ standard library* you caused everything that was compiled in C++ (requiring) it to be removed... which is why you shouldn't '-y' or "yes" without at least scanning packages looking for consequences.. (unless it's for learning sake & you have good backups). It didn't *wreck* the OS, you just lost access to any tool that required it (`dpkg` & many tools are written in C [not C++] so weren't impacted..), ie. learn...

Comment: @guiverc I'm glad a new installation is not necessary if I re-add the missing packages. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @ParsaMousavi And thank you so much for your help